# PostgreSQL timetz Entity Framework

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework

При использовании Entity Framework с бд PostgreSQL какой тип данных лучше использовать для маппинга поля таблицы, имеющим тип timetz? Пробовал TimeSpan (при этом теряется информация о часовом поясе, но это легко обходится на уровне приложения): при получении данных из бд всё работает отлично, но при сохранении в бд получаю ошибку "column 'time' is of type time with time zone but expression is of type interval"

Comment: DateTime, PostgreSQL вроде хранит даты с зоной

Answer (score 1):

Есть-таки решение проблемы. После использования такого сочетания:

```
 [Column("fTimeStart")]
 public DateTimeOffset Start { get; set; }
```

всё, наконец, заработало.